# Conversation Adding Second Phone Number Error 'Group MMS is not enabled'

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

In Twilio via the Rest API, I have

1. Generated a conversation fine
2. Added in a 'user' with a projected address of a Twilio phone number
3. Added in myself as a participant with the address being my phone number
4. Finally, I went to add one more participant with the address being a mobile phone number

The 4th step throws the following error:

> Group MMS is not enabled for this Account.
> https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/50452

I understand Group MMS is deprecated at this point (no new sign-on). However, I also believe Conversations supports having multiple users (some on mobile, some via "user" chat, some on WhatsApp, etc.) so I am not sure why it is automatically trying to convert it over to a 'Group MMS'. Is there a setting on the Conversation I can toggle to prevent it from trying and yet still support multiple participants on mobile? Or even on the participant level?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my issue.

1. When adding the user I gave it a "MessagingBinding.ProjectedAddress" which set it up for Group MMS
2. When adding the SMS participants, I did not provide them a  "MessagingBinding.ProxyAddress" (i.e. a Phone Number purchased from Twilio).

The combination of these two had Twilio thinking I wanted to use Group MMS the minute I added in a third participant. Instead, the following works:

1. Generate a conversation
2. Add in a 'user' with just an "Identity"
3. Added in myself as a participant with the address being my phone number and the proxyAddress being a Twilio phone number
4. Add in another participant with the address being a mobile phone number and the proxyAddress being a Twilio phone number (can be same proxyAddress as used in step 3)

The only extra note here is that the proxyAddress used must be distinct for that participant mobile phone number across all active conversations. As far as I can tell, Twilio does not have the concept of "sticky sender" that can be used for conversations so I am planning on tracking my own users phone number assignments.